# Add Javascript Autocomplete split function within another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

My knowledge of Javascript & jQuery is very limited but I managed, with some help, to get my autocomplete function where I would like it to be.

I want to limit the results of my autocomplete to any length I want. I know of the following code to limit the results:

```
source: function(request, response) {
    var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(airports, request.term);
    response(results.slice(0, 10));
}
```

but my "source" already uses a function to search through certain values & keys within my array for terms:

```
function airportArray(request, response) {
    var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
    response($.grep(airports, function(value) {
        return matcher.test(value.iata) || matcher.test(value.city) || matcher.test(value.airport);
    }));
}
```

How do I add the filter into my already coded function?

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/cgaybba/17p7uyvf/

I've tried many variations, but like I said, my knowledge is limited to combine the two functions successfully.

Any assistance will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to simply filter the results for at most 10 items you can just append the slice function to the returned array from `$.grep`:

```
  response(
     $.grep(airports, function(value) {
        return matcher.test(value.iata) || 
               matcher.test(value.city) ||   
               matcher.test(value.airport);
      })
     .slice(0, 10)
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    var cur = 0;
    var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
    response(
      $.grep(airports, function(value) {
          var result = matcher.test(value.iata) || matcher.test(value.city) || matcher.test(value.airport);           
          if (cur >= 10 && result == true) { result = false; } else { cur = cur + 1; }
          return result;
      })
    );
```

You were already almost there.